# Выгрузка данных из Excel в C# (DataTable) c определённого места

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дан такой Excel файл, нужно перетащить эти данные с Excel в DataTable (в последующую очередь в dataGridView1).
У меня для обработки взят следующий код:

```
OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
opf.Filter = "Excel (*.XLSX)|*.xlsx | All files (*.*)|*.*";
opf.ShowDialog();
DataTable tb1 = new DataTable();
string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(opf.FileName))
{
IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet("Лист1");
//Create a new DataTable.
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
bool firstRow = true;
foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
{
if (firstRow)
{
foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
{
dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
}
firstRow = false;
}
else
{
dt.Rows.Add();
int i = 0;
foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
{
dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1 ][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
i++;
}
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
}
```

Но этот код считывает весь файл Exсel, а не определённую область. Я пытался написать другой код, но у меня вылетали ошибки и я оставил так. У кого есть варианты кода, как начать загрузку данных с 8-ой строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов

```
            OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
            opf.Filter = "Excel (*.XLSX)|*.xlsx | All files (*.*)|*.*";
            opf.ShowDialog();
            System.Data.DataTable tb1 = new System.Data.DataTable();
            string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(opf.FileName))
            {
                IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet("Лист1");
                //Create a new DataTable.
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                bool firstRow = true;
                //foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
                for(int rowIndex=7; rowIndex< workSheet.Rows().Count(); rowIndex++)
                {
                    var row = workSheet.Rows().ElementAt(rowIndex);
                    if (firstRow)
                    {
                        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(cell.WorksheetColumn().ColumnLetter());
                        }
                        firstRow = false;
                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        i++;
                    }

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
```